# am a beginner in VB.net i try to create a hotel management

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class CONNECTION

Private connection As MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=vbnet_hotel_db")

'return the connection
Function GetConnection() As MySqlConnection
    Return connection


End Function
'open the connection
Sub OpenConnection()
    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()


    End If
End Sub
'close the connection
Sub CloseConnection()
    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        connection.Close()


    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC30638 Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.  Hotel
>   Management    C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\Hotel Management\Hotel
>   Management\CONNECTION.vb  4   Active
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC30311 Value of type 'MySqlConnection()' cannot be converted to
>   'MySqlConnection'.    Hotel
>   Management    C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\Hotel Management\Hotel
>   Management\CONNECTION.vb  8   Active

these are my errors. kindly help. thank you

Comment: Replace `Private connection As MySqlConnection("....")` with `Private connection As New MySqlConnection("....")`.

Comment: Please don't create a `CONNECTION` class. Just create and use connections in the methods where they are used. You can have a globally accessible connection string. Connections need to be closed and disposed. The .Dispose method release unmanaged code used by the connection. This will not be garbage collected so it could cause leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think you have a clash of types. Consider this code:

```
Public Class CONNECTION

Private connection As MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=vbnet_hotel_db")
```

You have a variable named `connection`, that has the **same name** as the containing class but in **lower case**. In VB.net variable names are not **case-sensitive**, so `CONNECTION` and `connection` refer to the same variable.

Obvious the two definitions clash with each other and no type casting is possible. They must have different names since they are two different things.

The problem here is the poor choice of object names. Avoid names that are too generic. Keep in mind that every programming language has reserved keywords. The list for VB.net is here: [Keywords (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/). Sometimes, it is possible to name variables after reserved keywords without the compiler protesting, but that can cause bugs that may be hard to troubleshoot (also see the section [Unreserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/#unreserved-keywords)). The bottom line: follow sound **naming conventions** and use meaningful, descriptive names for your variable and object names.

Comment: In this case, the class should be named something like `ConnectionManager`. The class doesn't represent a connection but, rather, something that manages a connection. The name should reflect that.